# Sharepoint Wiki forwarding

Tags: list, wiki, path

Good day,

I`ve been trying to implement a Wiki into our TeamShare. I would like to have the Wiki Pop up when clicking on the entry on the left Navigation bar. However, SP opens a list(1) with the Wiki lsited as a site, so you have to click that first to be led to the wiki(2). Any ideas how to Change the Routing?[image]

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Edit the left hand side nvigation menu through Website Settings (top right hand corner gear symbol). And then going to navigation.